# Open a router-view in a new tab?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

we are starting a new vuejs SPA application, the thing is that the client is asking to do something like a tabbed navigation.
i mean, each option of the menu, will open in a new closable tab, i was looking for this in here, but each solution that i find, is with all the tabs open from the start, the idea is to do it dynamic.

i've tried to persuade the client from this option, but i didn't have any luck with that, they are migrating the application from a MDI windows app, and somehow want to keep some functionalities.

is there any way to accomplish this task?

regards

Comment: what do you mean by 'all the tabs open from the start' could you give some more information or code snippet ?

Comment: i don't have a code snippet because i don't know where to start...

Comment: everything that i found on stackoverflow is similiar to this...

  <b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
    <b-tab title="First" active><p>I'm the first tab</p></b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Second"><p>I'm the second tab</p></b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Disabled" disabled><p>I'm a disabled tab!</p></b-tab>
  </b-tabs>

with all the tabs already defined... that's what i mean

Comment: how about you make a computed prop according to your need and do v-for loop on <b-tab> ?

Comment: and pushing a router-view to that? i don't get it how i could merge a router-view and a tab...

Comment: yes you can use @click="$router.push('dynamic url')" on your dynamic tabs;

Comment: but that should be done in an existing tab, and my tab wan't created yet.

Answer (score 1):

1) Store an object array that will be looped through to create tabs. When a tab is opened, add to the list, when a tab is closed, delete the tab from the list

```
tabs: [ { text: 'tab 1', 'route': 'routeName' },
 { text: 'tab 1', 'route': 'routeName' },
{ text: 'tab 1', 'route': 'routeName' }]
```

2) Create a router-view under the rendered tabs that will show the route when a tab is clicked

```
<b-tab v-for="tab in tabs"
@click="navigate(tab.route)>
  {{ tab.text }}
<v-tab>

<div>
  <router-view>
  </router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: cathy, i'm trying to  get this working, but as i'm using the hash navigation, is not working... :(

Comment: Ok, I gave this some thought and perhaps you can try using dynamic components? The documentation is here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html. This is assuming that you have coded each route into a component. Using dynamic components you can dynamically render components programmatically by their component name.

Comment: look i have an example here, you have to login with a fake user don/don and if you touch the magnifiyng glass you will get the new tabs...  https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/classic/ticket-app/ but the client don't want to use extjs.

Comment: Yeah this should be pretty easy to achieve with Vue. I found a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/wilcorrea/vue-router-with-dynamic-tabs